# Logistic regression appropriate with skewed outcomes?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model

I am currently examining a dataset pertaining to a specific behavior (chirping) in guinea pigs and the factors that influence whether a guinea pig will chirp or not. Previously, this behavior was thought to be quite rare (affecting about 1 in 10 piggies) but after conducting a survey, it appears that approximately 75% of pigs display this behavior every now and then. I thought about running a generalized linear model with a binary logistic link (chirps - does not chirp), since I have categorical (gender, reproductive status, etc.) and interval (age, number of companions) variables, but I am not sure logistic regression is appropriate for datasets where the distribution of the outcome variable is so heavily skewed in one direction.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: 75% should be OK.

Comment: Aren't age and number of companions ratio rather than interval?  I don't see any issue with something in the ballpark of a 75%-25% split for logistic regression

Comment: You are absolutely right, they are ratio, I was sort of tired when I wrote up the question, thank for the correction!